# What is the difference between Libsodium and Javax crypto

Tags: java, encryption, libsodium

I'm not a sercurity or a crypto expert. I want to perfrom encryption on my client to server communication in a RESTful api system.

Currently I'm using `javax crypto` and initializing the `Ciper` for `AES` with `AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding` to encrypt the data and `RSA` with `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding` to encrypt the `iV` and `Symmetric key` with a public key.
This works well for me.

I did some more digging on other encryption libraries and found `Libsodium` or [NaCl](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/).

I tried searching for any comparision between these and I'm not able to find any. Is it because I'm trying compare apples to oranges?

Should I continue with the `javax crypto` or should I switch to `sodium`? What benifits does `sodium` give over the default `javax crypto`?

Comment: Does NaCl support Java? From this page it seems like only C and C++:
- https://nacl.cr.yp.to/features.html

Comment: There's libsodium and jnacl in maven

Comment: libsodium tries to provide crypto interfaces that are reasonably high-level *and* difficult to shoot yourself in the foot with. Java crypto is lower-level and full to the brim with foot guns.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Can you elaborate on this? Like if we consider encryption algorithms as lego blocks, all we need to do is piece together the blocks to make a flow with java crypto (eg, generate iv, generate gcm spec, generate keys etc). But with libsodium we still need to provide the nonce and keys.

Comment: The usage of "external" libraries may be useful with "cross platform cryptography" (e.g. between Java and C/C++) as you have the same basis for your methods and data. If you stay within Java the JCE is a good starting point.

Comment: @MichaelFehr okay got it thanks :)